# c++: Storing a Variable Amount of Input into a Char Buffer

Tags: c++, user-input

I need to format my program to take a variable amount of input. By variable I mean that the number of lines in the input will not be known. Input shall be passed as followed:

```
cat input | ./myProg
```

I wrote this version of my program and it successfully grabs one line of input, stores it into a char buffer, and prints to the console:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    char outputData[1024];

    cin.getline(outputData,1024);

    cout << outputData;

    return 0;
}
```

i need help generalizing this program to grab a variable number of lines and store them in one large char buffer for manipulation later. I wrote the following code but it but does not print any information to the console:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{    
    char outputData[1024];

    while(!cin.eof())
    {
    cin.getline(outputData,1024);
    }

    cout << outputData;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or even [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current solution, you override the buffer's contents each loop, so it obviously won't print every line like you intent.

Anyways, you should be using `std::string` if you want to store variable amount of characters, your current code will only work for lines of 1024 characters or less. To store any number of lines, you can either concatenate all the lines into one big std::string, or if you want easier per-line access, you could store them in a `std::vector` of strings. To read directly into `std::string` and let C++ deal with the memory management for you, use `std::getline()` instead of `cin.getline()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

    // do something with lines, eg. print them by iterating through the vector
    // and printing each string in it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use strings and vectors.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::string> lines;

for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
{
    v.push_back(std::move(line));
}
```

<sub>Before anyone comes and suggests istream iterators and subclassing `std::string`, I dare you to do it in less code :-)</sub>

Comment: Is it ok to use `std::move()` like this? As far as I know, after move finishes, the implementation is free to assume that the variable that was moved from is not going to be re-used, but here it'll be used again in each input line.

Comment: @reko_t: It's fine. The object is in a valid state after the move.

Comment: Yeah just looked it up and it seems that it's fine, thanks for clarifying. :)

Comment: @BoPersson: every loop is a `for` loop :-) No other kind of loop contains the iterant variable in a sufficiently tight scope.